# How to import ReactBootstrap to use button in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using babel.js, try to import ReactBootstrap like this

```
const { Button } = ReactBootstrap.Button;
const { ButtonGroup } = ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup;
```

Error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactBootstrap is not defined
```

how to fix it?

Comment: how are you adding bootstrap to your project?

Comment: Can you share the whole code?

Answer (score 1):

Can you import like this way

```
  import { Button } from 'ReactBootstrap.Button'
  import { ButtonGroup } from 'ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup'
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined, need to use browsify to compile if using this kind of syntax?

Comment: @hkguile by default browsers will not allow use of import. You can either use a compiler like webpack or browserify to combine your JS into one file, or load your script with the 'type="module"' attribute to enable modules in the browser. You may also need to change the filename to ".mjs" for babel to handle that correctly. https://v8.dev/features/modules

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for importing your ReactBootstrap using ES5 syntax.

```
const { Button } = require("ReactBootstrap.Button");
const { ButtonGroup } = require("ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup");
```

Comment: If you want to use ES6 then you have to use import syntax. 

  import { Button } from 'ReactBootstrap.Button'
  import { ButtonGroup } from 'ReactBootstrap.ButtonGroup'

But as you might know, ES6 syntaxes are not supported in older versions of browsers. To make this work in every version you have to use a tool like webpack to transpile the syntax. You have to apply certain rules and loaders of webpack to convert these ES6 syntax.